# How to send deliver_sm request add user_message_reference TLV from node.js SMPP

Tags: node.js, smpp, tlv

I'm using [node-smpp](https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp) and would like to know how to send a "deliver_sm" request and add "TLV" response to user_message_reference.

Extract of [node-smpp / lib / smpp.js](https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp/blob/master/lib/smpp.js):

```js
exports.addTLV = function(tag, options) {
    options.tag = tag;
    defs.tlvs[tlv] = options;
    defs.tlvsById[options.id] = options;
};
```

Test code:

```js
var tlv = new Object();
tlv.tag = 0x001E; // smpp.receipted_message_id;
tlv.lenght =  msgid.lenght;
tlv.value = msgid;

smpp.addTLV(tlv,tlv);
```

Result:

```
defs.tlvs[tlv] = options;
       ^
ReferenceError: tlv is not defined
```

Comment: Is SMPP the module name? Also what does TLV mean?

Comment: TLV = Type-length-value a parameter added to PDU common with ASN.1 formatted protocols. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of node-smpp module.

To add either a tlv parameter or a standard parameter to your PDUs you just need to add a property to the pdu with the appropriate name.

```
session.deliver_sm({
    source_addr: 'blahblah',
    destination_addr: 'blahblah',
    short_message: 'blahblah',
    receipted_message_id: 'blahblah',
    user_message_reference: msgid
});
```

This will send a deliver_sm pdu with the above parameters plus other required paramenters set to their default values.

Generally you don't need to use `smpp.addTLV` at all. It is for defining custom vendor specific TLVs (tags between 0x1400 and 0x3FFF).

Comment: Hi, I know this answer is very older but anyway... I got ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined``` when trying to send a deliver_sm